# Classic thesis margins macro

Tags: macros, margins, classicthesis

Why if I use the `\documentclass{book}` for examples, the following code work, and if i use `classicthesis` i get errors? Sorry for the lenght, but this is the MWE.

In the example the `\textwidth` founded, don't is applied, so I don't think that the stuff related to the margins are implicated in the errors. The problem is with the .aux file for me.

---

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[%
           pdfspacing,%
           linedheaders,%
           ]{classicthesis}

        \usepackage{pgf}
        \usepackage{xparse}
        \usepackage{siunitx}
        \usepackage{environ}
        \usepackage{booktabs}
        \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,amsfonts}

% 1 comment this: \input{\nameofthisfile.aux} line
% 2 compile
% 3 uncomment this: \input{\nameofthisfile.aux} line
% 4 compile

%                                    put here the name of this .tex file
        \newcommand{\nameofthisfile}{testing}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\bool_new:N \g_has_run_bool
\tl_new:N \l_aw_text_tl
\int_new:N \l_aw_tot_int
\int_new:N \g_aw_tot_alph_int
\int_new:N \g_wid_space_int
\int_new:N \g_space_int
\fp_new:N \g_rat_space_int
\fp_new:N \g_aw_avg_width_fp
\dim_new:N \myalphabetwidth
\dim_new:N \mytextwidth
\input{\nameofthisfile.aux} %                                                           THIS LINE
\tl_const:Nn \c_aw_the_alphabet_tl {abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}

% this can be changed to an evironment or renamed or whatever
\NewDocumentCommand {\avgwidthstart} {}
  {
    \aw_avg_width:w
  }

\NewDocumentCommand {\avgwidthend}{}{}

% Here is the environment version, using just "text" as a name is probably a bad idea.
\NewEnviron{avgtext}
{
  \expandafter\avgwidthstart\BODY\avgwidthend
}

\makeatletter

\cs_new:Npn \aw_avg_width:w #1 \avgwidthend
  {
    % if first run, then generate variables to be used
    \bool_if:NF \g_has_run_bool
      {
        \tl_map_inline:Nn \c_aw_the_alphabet_tl
        {
          \int_new:c {g_##1_int}
          \fp_new:c {g_rat_##1_fp}
          \fp_new:c {g_wid_##1_fp}
        }
      }
    \tl_set:Nn \l_aw_text_tl {#1}

    % this can be used rather than the preceding line to take capital 
    % letters into account, but is Slooooooow
    %\tl_set:Nx \l_aw_text_tl {\tl_expandable_lowercase:n {#1}}

    \int_set:Nn \l_aw_tot_int {\tl_count:N \l_aw_text_tl}
    \tl_map_function:NN \c_aw_the_alphabet_tl \aw_get_counts:n
    \deal_with_spaces:n {#1}
    \tl_map_function:NN \c_aw_the_alphabet_tl \aw_calc_ratios:n
    \tl_map_function:NN \c_aw_the_alphabet_tl \aw_calc_avg_width:n
    \fp_gset_eq:NN \g_aw_avg_width_fp \l_tmpa_fp
    \fp_zero:N \l_tmpa_fp

    % the dimension \myalphabetwidth gives the width of the alphabet based on your character freq,
    % can be accessed by \the\myalphabetwidth
    \dim_gset:Nn \myalphabetwidth {\fp_to_dim:n {\fp_eval:n {26*\g_aw_avg_width_fp}}}

    % the dimension \mytextwidth gives the recommended \textwidth based on 66 chars per line.
    % can be accessed by \the\mytextwidth
    \dim_gset:Nn \mytextwidth {\fp_to_dim:n {\fp_eval:n {66*\g_aw_avg_width_fp}}}
    \protected@write\@mainaux{}{\mytextwidth=\the\mytextwidth}
    \bool_gset_true:N \g_has_run_bool

    % and lastly print the content
    #1
  }

\makeatother

\cs_new:Npn \aw_get_counts:n #1
  {
    % make a temporary token list from the document body 
    \tl_set_eq:NN \l_tmpb_tl \l_aw_text_tl
    % remove all occurrences of the character
    \tl_remove_all:Nn \l_tmpb_tl {#1}
    % add to appropriate int the number of occurrences of that character in current block
    \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int {\int_eval:n{\l_aw_tot_int -\tl_count:N \l_tmpb_tl}}
    % add to appropriate int the number of occurrences of that character in current block
    \int_gadd:cn {g_#1_int} {\l_tmpa_int}
    % add this to the total
    \int_gadd:Nn \g_aw_tot_alph_int {\l_tmpa_int}
  }

\cs_new:Npn \deal_with_spaces:n #1
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
    % rescan body with spaces as characters
    \tl_set_rescan:Nnn \l_tmpb_tl {\char_set_catcode_letter:N \ }{#1}
    % find number of new characters introduced.  add to number of spaces and alph chars
    \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int {\tl_count:N \l_tmpb_tl -\tl_count:N \l_tmpa_tl}
    \int_gadd:Nn \g_space_int {\l_tmpa_int}
    \int_gadd:Nn \g_aw_tot_alph_int {\l_tmpa_int}
    % since this comes after the rest of chars are dealt with, tot_alph is final total
    \fp_set:Nn \g_rat_space_fp {\g_space_int/\g_aw_tot_alph_int}
    % get width of space and use it.  obviously space is stretchable, so i'll assume
    % that the expansions and contractions cancel one another over large text.  is this
    % a terrible assumption???
    \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box {\ }
    \fp_gset:Nn \g_wid_space_fp {\dim_to_fp:n {\box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box}}
    \fp_add:Nn \l_tmpa_fp {\g_wid_space_fp*\g_rat_space_fp}
  }

\cs_new:Npn \aw_calc_ratios:n #1
  {
    % divide number of occurrences of char by total alphabetic chars
    \fp_gset:cn {g_rat_#1_fp}{{\int_use:c {g_#1_int}}/\g_aw_tot_alph_int}
  }

\cs_new:Npn \aw_calc_avg_width:n #1
  {
    % only need to find char widths once
    \bool_if:NF \g_has_run_bool
      {
        % find width of char box
        \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box {#1}
        \fp_gset:cn {g_wid_#1_fp}{\dim_to_fp:n {\box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box}}
      }
    % multiply it by char frequency and add to avg width
    \fp_add:Nn \l_tmpa_fp {{\fp_use:c {g_wid_#1_fp}}*{\fp_use:c {g_rat_#1_fp}}}
  }
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% This part is just for fun. Delete it and the showtable command from the document if
% it isn't wanted
    \newlength{\alphabet}%
    \settowidth{\alphabet}{\normalfont abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}%
\tl_new:N \l_aw_tab_rows_tl
\seq_new:N \g_aw_theor_rats_seq
\seq_new:N \g_aw_the_alphabet_seq

\seq_gset_split:Nnn \g_aw_theor_rats_seq {,}
{0.0651738,0.0124248,0.0217339,0.0349835,0.1041442,0.0197881,0.0158610,0.0492888,0.0558094,0.0009033,0.0050529,0.0331490,0.0202124,0.0564513,0.0596302,0.0137645,0.0008606,0.0497563,0.0515760,0.0729357,0.0225134,0.0082903,0.0171272,0.0013692,0.0145984,0.0007836,0.1918182}

\NewDocumentCommand {\showtable}{}
    {
      \clearpage
      \aw_make_table:
    }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn {NnV}
\cs_new:Npn \aw_make_table:
    {
      \thispagestyle{empty}
      \seq_set_split:NnV \g_aw_the_alphabet_seq {} \c_aw_the_alphabet_tl
      %takes corresponding letter/theoretical ratio pairs from sequences and applies function
      \seq_mapthread_function:NNN \g_aw_the_alphabet_seq \g_aw_theor_rats_seq \aw_generate_row:nn
      \begin{center}
        Total\,characters\,=\,\fp_eval:n {\g_aw_tot_alph_int}
      \end{center}
      \begin{table}[h]
      \centering
      \sisetup{round-mode = places,round-precision = 5,output-decimal-marker={,},table-format = 3.5}
      \begin{tabular}{llll}
        \toprule
        {Average\,\texttt{\textbackslash textwidth}}&{Average\,character\,width}&{Average\,alphabet\,width}&{Alphabet\,width}\\
        \midrule
        \the\mytextwidth&\fp_eval:n {round(\g_aw_avg_width_fp,5)}pt&\the\myalphabetwidth&\the\alphabet\\
        \bottomrule
      \end{tabular}\par
      \end{table}
      \vfil
      \begin{equation*}
      \begin{split}
      \,\texttt{\textbackslash textwidth}&=\frac{\fp_eval:n {\g_aw_tot_alph_int}\cdot \fp_eval:n {round(\g_aw_avg_width_fp,5)}\mathrm{pt}}{\fp_eval:n {\g_aw_tot_alph_int}/66}=\fp_eval:n {\g_aw_tot_alph_int*{round(\g_aw_avg_width_fp,5)}/({\g_aw_tot_alph_int}/66)}\mathrm{pt}\\
      \\1
      \mathrm{Total\,line\,type}&=\frac{\fp_eval:n {\g_aw_tot_alph_int}\cdot \fp_eval:n {round(\g_aw_avg_width_fp,5)}\mathrm{pt}}{\fp_eval:n {\g_aw_tot_alph_int*{round(\g_aw_avg_width_fp,5)}/({\g_aw_tot_alph_int}/66)}\mathrm{pt}}=\fp_eval:n {\g_aw_tot_alph_int/66}\\
      \\
      \mathrm{Characters\,for\,line\,type}&=\frac{\fp_eval:n {round(\g_aw_avg_width_fp,5)}\mathrm{pt}}{\fp_eval:n {\g_aw_tot_alph_int*{round(\g_aw_avg_width_fp,5)}/({\g_aw_tot_alph_int}/66)}\mathrm{pt}}=\fp_eval:n {\fp_eval:n {(\g_aw_tot_alph_int*{round(\g_aw_avg_width_fp,5)}/({\g_aw_tot_alph_int}/66))/round(\g_aw_avg_width_fp,5)}}
      \end{split}
      \end{equation*}
      \vfil
      \begin{table}[h]
      \centering
      \sisetup{round-mode = places,round-precision = 5,output-decimal-marker={,},table-format = 3.5}
      \begin{tabular}{cSSS}
        \toprule
        {Letter}&{Actual}&{Theoretical}&{Difference}\\
        \midrule
        spaces&\fp_eval:n {\g_rat_space_fp*100}\%&19.18182\%&\fp_eval:n {{\g_rat_space_fp*100-19.18182}}\%\\
        \tl_use:N \l_aw_tab_rows_tl
        \bottomrule
      \end{tabular}\par
      \end{table}
    }

\cs_new:Npn \aw_generate_row:nn #1#2
    {
      \tl_put_right:Nn \l_aw_tab_rows_tl {#1&}
      \tl_put_right:Nx \l_aw_tab_rows_tl {\fp_eval:n {100*{\fp_use:c {g_rat_#1_fp}}}\%&}
      \tl_put_right:Nn \l_aw_tab_rows_tl {\fp_eval:n{100*{#2}}\%&}
      \tl_put_right:Nx \l_aw_tab_rows_tl {\fp_eval:n {{\fp_use:c {g_rat_#1_fp}*100-\fp_eval:n {#2}*100}}\%}
      \tl_put_right:Nn \l_aw_tab_rows_tl {\\}
    }

\ExplSyntaxOff



\begin{document}

\avgwidthstart
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean faucibus luctus diam, id convallis mauris faucibus ut. Aenean accumsan dignissim posuere. Praesent et diam nec est lobortis faucibus. Fusce sit amet placerat velit. Curabitur tortor velit, imperdiet imperdiet condimentum in, blandit ac augue. In vulputate volutpat ligula, malesuada porta mi eleifend at. Praesent ut augue vel nulla molestie ornare ac a sem. Donec luctus volutpat ipsum sed consectetur. Maecenas at lacus a tortor congue blandit. Vestibulum elementum risus dapibus sem blandit adipiscing. Pellentesque vulputate ullamcorper vulputate. In suscipit facilisis libero.
\avgwidthend

\showtable{}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you explain again what your problem is? Your example runs without errors here.

Comment: @StephanLehmke really do you have not errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The real problem is *in* the `.aux` file you're inputting. You find there commands like

```
\providecommand\hyper@newdestlabel[2]{}
\@writefile{toc}{\vspace {-\cftbeforechapskip }}
\@writefile{lof}{\deactivateaddvspace  }
\@writefile{lot}{\deactivateaddvspace  }
```

That means, the `.aux` file expects `@` to be a letter.

Moving `\makeatletter` (which you're using anyway) upward before `\input{\nameofthisfile.aux}` makes the error go away.

btw, `\jobname` is set by the system to the name of the input file.